# Physical significance of electric fields (part 2 I guess)

Tags: electromagnetism

> " The true physical significance of the concept of electric field, however, emerges only when we deal with time dependent electromagnetic phenomena. Suppose we consider the force between two distant charges q1, q2 in accelerated motion . Now, the greatest speed with which a signal can go from one point to another is c, the speed of light. Thus , the effect of any motion of q1 on q2 cannot arise instantaneously. There will be some time delay between the effect(force on q2) and the cause (motion of q1) . It is precisely here that the notion of electric field ( strictly, EM field) is natural and very useful. **The field picture is this : the accelerated motion of charge q1 produces electromagnetic waves, which then propagate with the speed c, reach q2 and cause a force on q2 . The notion of electric field elegantly accounts for the time delay.** Thus, even though electric and magnetic fields are detected only by their effects(forces) on charges, they are regarded as physical entities, not merely mathematical constructs . They have an independent dynamics of their own. They can transport energy. Thus, a source of time-dependent electromagnetic fields, turned on briefly and switched off, leaves behind propagating electromagnetic field transporting energy. The concept of field was first introduced by Faraday and is now among the central concepts of physics. "

This can be said to be a continuation of a certain question from 21 months ago and the problem is that most of the questions went unanswered in it. So I guess you can say I want to learn and understand those questions pointed out by the other guy.
For context, here's the link :- [Physical significance of electric fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705459/)

A question I want to specify
-> How do electromagnetic fields explain the time delay caused?

I welcome a detailed explanation containing all the necessary links to understand this throughly.

PS. I am still a padawan in this particular topic, to be more exact this particular topic is in my grade 12 NCERT textbook (page 20, can vary based on which edition you are looking into).